# Setting a custom design size for a UITabViewController (in Storyboard)

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, size, uistoryboard

I want to modify an app that currently has a `UITabBarController` as its initial view controller.

The goal is to have a custom status bar in the top area of the screen that will always be shown no matter which tab is selected. The current `UITabBarController` may not use the full height of the screen:

```
/----------------------------\
|Custom Status bar (50 px)   |
|                            |
|----------------------------|
|                            |
|----------------------------| ---
|                            |  |
|                            |  |
|View of the selected tab    |  |
|                            |  |
|                            |  |
|                            |  |
|                            |  | 
|                            |  smaller height of the UITabBarController
|                            |  |
|----------------------------|  |
|Tab bar                     |  |
|                            |  |
\----------------------------/ ---
```

I use storyboards. I cannot set a (design) size in the `Size Inspector` window even with simulated metrics size set to 'freeform'.

Comment: Did you try implementing your container controller programmatically ? You could then use story boarding to create the view controllers of each tab buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your `UITabBar` programmatically like so:

```
UITabBar *myTabBar = [[UITabBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
[MyView addSubview:myTabBar];
```

You should see ['s documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on the subject for more information about setting up your `UITabBar` programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this can not be done in a storyboard or xib.

The only way to put a UITabBarController inside of another view controller is by creating a container view controller and adding it to that in code.

In this case, you would need to create a new UIViewController, and then call `addChildViewController:childController` for each of the view controllers that you want to display (once for your header, and once for the tab bar controller).

See the **Implementing a Container View Controller** section of the **[UIViewController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)** for more information.